# Ruby On Rails REST: Customize URL pattern for POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, rubygems, rails-routing

I am new to Ruby On Rails and need some help implementing REST protocol.

Whenever you do a POST on REST you get a URL back e.g. `http://my-site.com/id/1`
I need a customized response in URL format which I have given in example above.
Lets say I am doing a post on parameter `<main-id>123</main-id>`
The customized response I am looking for is `http://my-site.com/123/id/1` 
What I want to implement is, whatever parameter ID I passed during a post I want that as a part of the response URL output.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify any URL in your controller, e.g.:

```
def create
  ... # create record here
  redirect_to "/#{params[:main_id]}/id/#{@record.id}"
end
```

Of course, you'll probably want to use the url helper based on your defined route:

```
def create
  ... # create record here
  redirect_to my_oddball_path(@record, :main_id => 123)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using Rails 3, you could just add this route with the proper controller/action

```
 match ':main_id/id/:id', :controller => 'foo', :action => "bar", :via => :post, :as => main_id
```

Then you can just with the helper main_id_path(main_id, @record)